# Generating an inverse index

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, inverse

I have the following:

```
strlist = ['the', 'the', 'boy', 'happy', 'boy', 'happy']
{x:{(list(enumerate(strlist))[y])[0]} for y in range(len(strlist)) for x in (strlist)}
```

My output is the following:

```
{'boy': set([5]), 'the': set([5]), 'happy': set([5])}
```

My issue is that I'd like to output this (using python 3.x):

```
{'boy': {2,4}, 'the': {0,1}, 'happy': {3,5} }
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: What's surprising about that? It's the set with the two indices of `'boy'` in `strlist`.

Comment: @abarnert: `>>> {2,4}` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: `>>> {2,4}` `set([2, 4])`. Python 3.x has set literals. So does 2.7. If you're going to answer Python 3.x questions, don't try to run the code in 2.5.

Comment: @abarnert: sry, I simply didn't know about set literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> strlist = ['the', 'the', 'boy', 'happy', 'boy', 'happy']
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(set)
>>> for i, s in enumerate(strlist):
...     D[s].add(i)
... 
>>> D
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'boy': {2, 4}, 'the': {0, 1}, 'happy': {3, 5}})
```

If you can't use `defaultdict` for some reason

```
>>> D = {}
>>> for i, s in enumerate(strlist):
...     D.setdefault(s, set()).add(i)
... 
>>> D
{'boy': {2, 4}, 'the': {0, 1}, 'happy': {3, 5{}
```

Here is the silly (inefficient) way to write it as a comprehension

```
>>> {k: {i for i, j in enumerate(strlist) if j == k} for k in set(strlist)}
{'boy': {2, 4}, 'the': {0, 1}, 'happy': {3, 5}}
```

Comment: @ gribbler Unfortunately, it needs to be a comprehension and no defaultdict utilization :/

Comment: @JessePet, the requirement for a comprehension is silly (You can tell your teacher I said that). It's forcing you to use an inefficient algorithm for no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
dict(((string, set(i for i,w in enumerate(strlist) if w == string)) for string in strlist))
```

but note it has quadratic runtime, so it is only useful for very small amounts of data.

**Test case and sample output**: http://ideone.com/4sxUNf

Comment: This is close, but I'd like to keep it in the form:

    {string:{i:j} for string in ...}

etc.

Comment: I tried manipulating what you have, and came up with this:

    {string:{i} for (i,j) in enumerate(strlist) for string in strlist if j==string}

However, I still get:

    {'boy': set([4]), 'the': set([1]), 'happy': set([5])}

Comment: @JessePet, which version of Python are you using? Looks more like Python2 output

Comment: @gnibbler: I am using python 3.2.3.

Comment: @JessePet, Python 3.2.3 won't print sets like `set([4])` it prints `{4}`. Check again that you're running the correct version

Comment: @gnibbler Sorry, I was checking my code on repl.it which runs on Python 2.7.3, but using this:

`{string:{i} for (i,j) in enumerate(strlist) for string in strlist if j==string}` in 3.2.3 yields `{'boy': {4}, 'the': {1}, 'happy': {5}}`

Comment: @JessePet, yes it's a bit more complicated, see the last part of my answer

Comment: @gnibbler:  You mean your comment about (O)^2?  Yeah, this is supposed to be done with little knowledge on efficient algorthms.  Just part of an intro class.

Comment: @JessePet, no, I meant the part when I wrote `{k: {i for i, j in enumerate(strlist) if j == k} for k in set(strlist)}`

Comment: @gnibbler, unfortunately `{k: {i for i, j in enumerate(strlist) if j == k} for k in set(strlist)}` will not submit.  If it helps, here is the prompt:

**Write a procedure makeInverseIndex(strlist) that, given a list of strings (documents), returns
a dictionary that maps each word to the set consisting of the document numbers of documents in which that
word appears. This dictionary is called an inverse index. (Hint: use enumerate.)**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32886/discussion-between-jesse-pet-and-gnibbler)